# Free Transform Android Image

Tags: android, image, matrix, bitmap, transform

I would like to free transform an Android image. I have gotten comfortable using a matrix to skew a bitmap see below (just imagine the red shape is replaced with a bitmap or jpeg image):

[image]

What I want to do is be able to free transform the image. So for example only move 1 corner and have the other corners stay in the same location. What is an effective way of doing that?

Is there some sort of matrix math that I would need to do to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setPolyToPoly not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650809/setpolytopoly-not-applied)

matrix.setpolytopoly addresses this issue. Above is a link that I found to it.

Comment: Just for the sake of anyone googling here, if you have to do this in iOS, thank goodness there's a cut and paste code solution here for modern swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39981054/294884  unfortunately iOS has no such handy "poly to poly" method.